# angular2 shows npm error after npm start

Tags: angular

I have made an npm app. When i created it works fine. but after I have restart my desktop it is showing npm error. What should I do?
Here is my npm-debug.log file.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',

1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'run',

1 verbose cli   'lite' ]

2 info using npm@2.15.8

3 info using node@v4.4.7

4 verbose run-script [ 'prelite', 'lite', 'postlite' ]

5 info prelite angular2@1.0.0

6 info lite angular2@1.0.0

7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 info angular2@1.0.0 Failed to exec lite script

9 verbose stack Error: angular2@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`

9 verbose stack Exit status 1

9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:217:16)

9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)

9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)

9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)

9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)

9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)

9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)

9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

10 verbose pkgid angular2@1.0.0

11 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\angular2

12 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600

13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "lite"

14 error node v4.4.7

15 error npm  v2.15.8

16 error code ELIFECYCLE

17 error angular2@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`

17 error Exit status 1

18 error Failed at the angular2@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.

18 error This is most likely a problem with the angular2 package,

18 error not with npm itself.

18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:

18 error     lite-server

18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:

18 error     npm bugs angular2

18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:

18 error

18 error     npm owner ls angular2

18 error There is likely additional logging output above.

19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: There's too little information... What does the app have? What code? What command were you trying that yielded that error? What command worked before?

Answer (score 0):

please check what is command you have written in package.json

```
"script":{
 "start": "npm run dev" // example
}
```

what is that command which cauing ERROR